# How I can to set array data to the cells in column xlwings

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I work with excel sheet with python and xlwings

I need to format information from column N and set it in column Q

I managed to format the date
Uploaded data to the array
Now I need to upload this data to the Q column

I tried different options, but only the last value is loaded from the array to the entire column
How do I make the data appear in column Q?

```
from datetime import datetime
import datetime
import locale
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book('altpsychology.csv')
my_sht = wb.sheets[0]
array = my_sht .range('N:N')[1:].value
newArray = []

for k in array:
    if k != None:
            newArray.append(k)
intArray =([int(newArray) for newArray in newArray])
arr = []
for s in intArray:
    timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(s)
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, ('ru_RU', 'UTF-8'))
    arr.append(timestamp.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S"))

print(arr)
```

```
When i Try to run my code I expected that every array element will be in sungle cell of column Q
But there was only one last element in every cell in column

I can add to my question
How to set any array in column, I Each element of the array was in each cell of the column
I tried to set there array, but there was only the last element of the array

import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Book('mys.xlsx')
my_sht = wb.sheets[0]
array = my_sht.range('B1:B10').value
print(array)
newArray = [1,2,3,4,5,12,35,56,23,123,45,65]
for k in range(len(newArray)):
    for n in array:
        array[n] = my_sht.range('B1:B10').value = newArray[k]
```

[image]

> enter image description here

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFdY7.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFdY7.png)

Answer (score 0):

For my task I find solution in module xlsx writer
I just need this code from the documentation

```
import xlsxwriter
```

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('write_list.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for row_num, data in enumerate(my_list):
worksheet.write(row_num, 0, data)

workbook.close()